# PHP preg_split() for new line comma colon and space

Tags: php, preg-split

This is my code in .php:

```
$new_split = preg_split("/\s*[:, ]\s*/",$full_list,2);
print_r ($new_split);
```

Input ($full_list) is:

```
abcd : xyz
abcd efgh, ijk ,lmn
abcd lmnop
abcd: efghijk
abcd,efgh
```

Output is:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => abcd 
    [1] => xyz abcd efgh, ijk ,lmn abcd lmnop abcd: efghijk abcd,efgh *
)
```

I want to split based on new line comma (,) colon (:) and space. Please let me know how to get the below output.

Expected output is:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => abcd 
    [1] => xyz 
    [2] => abcd 
    [3] => efgh 
    [4] => ijk 
    [5] => lmn 
    [6] => abcd 
    [7] => lmnop 
    [8] => abcd 
    [9] => efghijk 
    [10] => abcd 
    [11] =>efgh 
)
```

Comment: The 2 in your preg_split command is the LIMIT parameter. You limiting it to two results. Remove the 2 completely to get all of them.

Comment: This is the output:
    Array ( [0] => abcd [1] => xyz abcd [2] => efgh [3] => ijk [4] => lmn abcd [5] => lmnop abcd [6] => efghijk abcd [7] => efgh ) 


$new_split = preg_split("/\s*[:, ]\s*/",$full_list);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `\s*` around the character class and change single space by `\s` inside the character class, add also a quantifier (ie. `+` for 1 or more):

```
$new_split = preg_split("/[:,\s]+/",$full_list,2);
print_r ($new_split);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `\s` inside the brackets like this: `$new_split = preg_split("/\s*[:,\s]\s*/",$full_list);`

Comment: Great!!! It works... Thank you :)

Array ( [0] => abcd [1] => xyz [2] => abcd [3] => efgh [4] => ijk [5] => lmn [6] => abcd [7] => lmnop [8] => abcd [9] => efghijk [10] => abcd [11] => efgh)